# Mogrify command works from CMD but not from .bat file

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, mogrify

I execute the following command (turn all black color elements to pink in any image) with CMD and it works perfectly ( all the images are changed):

```
mogrify -path img/images img/images/*.* -fuzz 95% -fill pink -opaque black img/images/*.*
```

but when using the same command on .bat file, only some images are changed and other are changes to the wrong result (some images turn black with pink frame):

```
@echo off 
cd /d "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16"
mogrify -path img/images img/images/*.* -fuzz 10% -fill pink -opaque  black img/images/*.*
```

any ideas why?

Comment: Wny have you got `img/images/*.*` twice in your command - omit the first one/

Comment: Also, you have to double up `%` signs inside batch files for some daft reason, so your `-fuzz 10%` may need to be `-fuzz 10%%` inside a batch script.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks! it solved the issue!

Comment: Excellent! I have put it as an answer for all to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double up your percent signs when inside a batch file... see Anthony Thyssen's excellent ImageMagick examples and notes [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/#conversion).

So, your `-fuzz 10%` will need to become `-fuzz 10%%` inside a batch file.